# Why ndim = 2 in this numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
>import numpy as np

>a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)

([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],

 [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],

 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])

> a.shape 
(3, 5)

> a.ndim 
2 /// how to calculate it for any narray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ndim` is the same as `len(a.shape)`

in your case you have 2 dimensions, first of size 3 and second of size 5